# File Upload windows Java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So i am having issues with the File Upload window for Chrome using Java Selenium

Now the Input[file='type'] solution doesnt work so i was forced to use Robot

Which works as long as the window in focus is the correct one as its a 'fire and forget' solution

Now when running headerless this fails consistently

When i automated in c# i used auto it (the nuget package) which worked brilliantly. There seems to be no Java equivalent (well one that doesnt involve installing JACOB locally or running a local autoit script which fails when run headerlessly)

So i looked thru Stack overflow and many of the answers are old and just suggest all the methods i have tried above

Have any better solutions appeared recently?

Thanks!

Comment: You’ll need to detail why the `sendKeys` solution “doesn’t” work for you.

Comment: I just checked using the sendKey to the `<input>` tag and it worked fine. Using latest Chrome and Chromedriver.

Comment: It is in the dom (although when i look for it, it highlights a square at the top of the page nowhere near the actual 'browse' button). When i run the script it says it cant find the eleemnt